# Windows File/Folder Sharing - custom network path

Tags: windows, network-shares, file-sharing, windows-server

I'm trying to simplify/shorten a windows shared network folder so that it's easier for my users to access. On the host computer where the path resides, I would like to share an entire drive to the netowork. The current path is:

```
\\fileshare\d
```

The "\d" is the drive on the computer "fileshare" that I'm currently sharing.

I was wondering if it is in any way possible to make it so typing `\\fileshare`
would redirect to the \d folder.

Thanks!

Comment: No.  Windows networking does not work that way.  You might look into Junctions or Hardlinks.  You might find your solution there.

Comment: does it matter that the host computer is on windows server 2022?

Comment: Do you have an Active Directory domain in place? If so, why don't you just map the share as a network drive for the users via a GPO?

Comment: @FastEthernet yes I do have AD running. I was not aware you could do that via GPO. Very nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated what you want is not possible.

A solution would be to automatically map the share as a network drive using a Group Policy Object (GPO).

[How To Map Network Drives With Group Policy (Complete Guide)](https://activedirectorypro.com/map-network-drives-with-group-policy/)

Comment: That wizard only creates device names in the form "a:", the default "drive letter" format. That's not a windows requirement. If you edit the gpo with a gpo editor, you may be able to name the device "fileshare" instead of "x:".

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if it is in any way possible to make it so typing `\\fileshare` would redirect to the \d folder.

No; SMB is fundamentally based around named "shares" and there's no mode to opt out of that.

Comment: The only reason why I thought it might be possible is that on my Domain Controller I know windows creates a default \\NETLOGON folder that is accessible on the domain. I was looking to make a custom "netlogon" folder if possible.

Comment: That doesn't actually change anything in terms of functionality, as far as I know; you still have to explicitly visit `\\example.com\netlogon`, not just `\\netlogon`? (The netlogon folder is implemented via DFS, but that only makes it visible "on the domain" as opposed to specific server; it still doesn't turn it into a default share.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity , yeah.. I know.. I was thinking if OP wanted to shortcut or simplify access to the users, junctions and hardlinks might provide another tool for the box.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: You can't link the "server root" though – `\\myserver` doesn't lead to a real path that exists anywhere, it always leads to the list of shares. That's the problem.